# How to retrieve context after a outliner.orphans_purge()

Tags: python, objects, memory-management

I've got a script that joins several object into one at every frame and then do several operations on the duplicated object.

However, I know that when a object is deleted in blender, meshes are stored as orphan data until next start up of the file. We can force the use of blender's garbage collector but I have a strange behavior when the script is interpreted. Here is the script :

```
def main(context):
    selectedOBJ = context.selected_objects

    for i in range(context.scene.frame_start, context.scene.frame_end+1):
        context.scene.frame_set(i)

        for obj in selectedOBJ:
            obj.select = True

        bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
        context.scene.objects.active = context.selectable_objects[0]
        bpy.ops.object.join()
        bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
        bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_remove()
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True,
                                       rotation=True,
                                       scale=True)
        context.selected_objects[0].name = "mergedRigidBodies__" + \
                                               str(i).zfill(5)
        selectedData = context.selected_objects[0].data
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(selectedData)

        context.area.type = 'OUTLINER'
        context.space_data.display_mode = 'ORPHAN_DATA'
        bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
        context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

After line bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge(), i've got an error that "Nonetype" doesn't have an attribute type, so I guess I've lost the context somehow. However I tried to print something after the orphan_purge() and it worked so I know that the script is not stopped after the said line.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem eventually?